# Curl Error code 7

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am encountering a curl request issue on some client machines. Although the http request works in the browser and on most of the win 7 64 bit sp1 machines, it fails on some user machines. 
Your inputs are appreciate. Here is the code stub using curl.

Thank you

```
bool HttpClient::request(const ArStr& url, HttpBuffer& header, HttpBuffer& body, unsigned long& status, ArStr& contentEncoding
    , bool bFollowRedirect /*= true*/, bool bForceNoCache /*= false*/, bool bForceNoCookie /*= true*/)
{
    try
    {
        bool ret = false;

        CURL *curl_handle;

        /* init the curl session */
        curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl_handle == NULL)
        {
            Logger::Instance()->Error(_T("Failed to init curl"));
            return ret;
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

        unsigned long nConnectTimeout = _nConnectTimeout;

        if (bFollowRedirect)
            curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        if (bForceNoCookie)
            curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1); // Set this value to ensure the session does not reuse old cookie, by default it is 0

        if (bForceNoCache)
            curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); // By default it is 0

        //add proxy setting with scheme

        char strProxy[1024] = { 0 };
       curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, strProxy);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, &nConnectTimeout);

        unsigned long nTimeout = max(_nReceiveTimeout, _nSendTimeout);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, &nTimeout);
        struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Test: data");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        /* no progress meter please */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);

        /* send all data to this function  */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, &header);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &body);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, debug_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // For outputing debug information
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        /* get it! */
        CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
        try
        {
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            Logger::Instance()->Error(_T("Failed to post data to %s, exception: %s"), url.c_str(), ex.what());
            res = CURLE_HTTP_POST_ERROR;
        }
        Logger::Instance()->Info(_T("status %d"), status);
        Logger::Instance()->Info(_T("curl result %d"), res);

        curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &status);

        char *ct;
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
        if (ct != NULL)
            contentEncoding = Utils::StringToArStr(ct);

        _lastInetErrorCode = res;

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            Logger::Instance()->Error(_T("Failed to send HTTP request, error code: %d"), res);
            ret = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = true;
        }

        /* cleanup curl stuff */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

        return ret;
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        Logger::Instance()->Error(_T("Failed to send http request"), ex.what());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[List of return codes of cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

> CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)
>
> Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

Comment: I looked up this error code already. But why does it fail ( the http request on browser works )

Comment: @PriyaRajput Firewall ? Network timeout ? Same private network ? Some weird window security ?